# ASP.NET Core 6 Web App, spike in exception count after CPU% spike

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-aks

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 web app running in a AKS environment. The .NET runtime metrics is showing that, after a spike in CPU%, some exceptions are also thrown.

[image]

How normal is such a behavior? Is there a correlation between a high CPU usage and possible exceptions being thrown? I'm asking this because the graph shows that the exceptions appeared after the CPU spike.

Comment: What are the exception types?

Comment: The prometheus-net package doesn't expose such things so I do not know exactly what types of exceptions were thrown internally by the runtime. I have a lot of exception handlers and I do not catch anything (so maybe they are first-chance exceptions?)